# Monthly Turnover with Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate employee turnover.

Employee turnover = (Avg_Terminations / Avg_Headcount)

I can find counts, but I am having trouble using those values in calculations. I've tried messing around with Pandas' monthly rolling window function but have been unsuccessful.

**Sample Data**

```
Date,Status,Gender,var1,salary,Age,Timetype,ID
1/31/2020,Terminated,Male,A,87181,39,Full,1
1/31/2020,Active,Male,B,122881,39,Full,2
1/31/2020,Active,Male,B,55993,65,Part,3
1/31/2020,Active,Male,A,226912,23,Full,4
1/31/2020,Active,Male,B,63368,48,Part,5
1/31/2020,Active,Male,B,174461,61,Full,6
1/31/2020,Active,Male,A,145231,20,Full,7
1/31/2020,Active,Male,A,216212,36,Full,8
1/31/2020,Active,Male,B,203799,51,Full,9
1/31/2020,Active,Male,A,163460,61,Full,10
1/31/2020,New Hire,Male,B,80643,49,Part,11
1/31/2020,Active,Female,A,225508,24,Full,12
1/31/2020,Active,Female,A,79962,31,Part,13
1/31/2020,Active,Female,A,141832,44,Full,14
1/31/2020,Active,Female,A,93677,47,Full,15
1/31/2020,Active,Female,B,133170,25,Full,16
1/31/2020,Terminated,Female,B,235365,32,Full,17
1/31/2020,Active,Female,A,160929,47,Full,18
1/31/2020,Active,Female,B,175020,62,Full,19
1/31/2020,Active,Female,B,100000,59,Full,20
2/29/2020,New Hire,Male,B,80643,49,Part,21
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,122881,39,Full,2
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,55993,65,Part,3
2/29/2020,Active,Male,A,226912,23,Full,4
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,63368,48,Part,5
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,174461,61,Full,6
2/29/2020,Terminated,Male,A,145231,20,Full,7
2/29/2020,Active,Male,A,216212,36,Full,8
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,203799,51,Full,9
2/29/2020,Terminated,Male,A,163460,61,Full,10
2/29/2020,Active,Male,B,80643,49,Part,11
2/29/2020,Active,Female,A,225508,24,Full,12
2/29/2020,Active,Female,A,79962,31,Part,13
2/29/2020,Active,Female,A,141832,44,Full,14
2/29/2020,Active,Female,A,93677,47,Full,15
2/29/2020,Active,Female,B,133170,25,Full,16
2/29/2020,New Hire,Female,B,120000,25,Full,22
2/29/2020,Active,Female,A,160929,47,Full,18
2/29/2020,Active,Female,B,175020,62,Full,19
2/29/2020,Active,Female,B,100000,59,Full,20
3/31/2020,Terminated,Male,B,80643,49,Part,21
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,122881,39,Full,2
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,55993,65,Part,3
3/31/2020,Active,Male,A,226912,23,Full,4
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,63368,48,Part,5
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,174461,61,Full,6
3/31/2020,New Hire,Male,A,100000,45,Full,22
3/31/2020,Active,Male,A,216212,36,Full,8
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,203799,51,Full,9
3/31/2020,New Hire,Male,A,200000,25,Full,23
3/31/2020,Active,Male,B,80643,49,Part,11
3/31/2020,Active,Female,A,225508,24,Full,12
3/31/2020,Active,Female,A,79962,31,Part,13
3/31/2020,Active,Female,A,141832,44,Full,14
3/31/2020,Active,Female,A,93677,47,Full,15
3/31/2020,Active,Female,B,133170,25,Full,16
3/31/2020,Active,Female,B,120000,25,Full,22
3/31/2020,Active,Female,A,160929,47,Full,18
3/31/2020,Active,Female,B,175020,62,Full,19
3/31/2020,Terminated,Female,B,100000,59,Full,20
```

I can get counts/sums with groupby

```
df.groupby(['Date','Status','Gender']])
```

**Counts**

```
Monthly counts by Status, Gender
                             var1  salary  Age  Timetype  ID
Date      Status     Gender                                 
1/31/2020 Active     Female     8       8    8         8   8
                     Male       9       9    9         9   9
          New Hire   Male       1       1    1         1   1
          Terminated Female     1       1    1         1   1
                     Male       1       1    1         1   1
2/29/2020 Active     Female     8       8    8         8   8
                     Male       8       8    8         8   8
          New Hire   Female     1       1    1         1   1
                     Male       1       1    1         1   1
          Terminated Male       2       2    2         2   2
3/31/2020 Active     Female     8       8    8         8   8
                     Male       8       8    8         8   8
          New Hire   Male       2       2    2         2   2
          Terminated Female     1       1    1         1   1
                     Male       1       1    1         1   1
```

i.e., If I wanted to calculate the total turnover for these 3 months, I would take:

**Avg_terminations** = (2 + 2 + 2) / 3 = 2

**Avg_headcount** = (18 + 18 + 18) / 3 = 18 (**Note, I am including New Hire's in headcount*)

**Turnover** = (2 / 18) * 100 = **11.11%** (*Running Turnover from end of Jan-end of Mar*)

Ideally I would like to be able to filter the Turnover by categories (i.e., Gender, Timetype, etc.)

How do I go about working this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the turn over rate using:

```
len(df) / df.Status.ne('Terminated').sum() - 1
# 0.1111111111111111
```

Similarly, to calculate turnover by categories:

```
df.groupby(['Gender', 'Timetype']).Status.agg(lambda g: len(g) / g.ne('Terminated').sum() - 1)

#Gender  Timetype
#Female  Full        0.090909
#        Part        0.000000
#Male    Full        0.157895
#        Part        0.100000
#Name: Status, dtype: float64
```